# Twitter scanner

Tags: php, optimization

How can I script this in a better way?

```
// Tweets

$twitter_username_string = "aasampat OR ashwinsampat OR somemore";
$twitter_number_of_tweets = 1;
$twitter_hashtags = "ashwinsampat+OR+franq2+OR+franq2.net";

// Instantiate a Twitter object which will scan Twitter depending on the parameters
$twitter = new Twitter($twitter_username_string, $twitter_number_of_tweets, $twitter_hashtags);
$tweets = $twitter->getTweets();

foreach ( $tweets as $tweet )
{
    $tweetoutput = "<p>".$tweet->title." <em>Tweeted by <a href=".$tweet->permalink." target=_blank title=@".$tweet->user.">".$tweet->author."</em></a></p>";
}
$twitter_username_string = "aasampat OR ashwinsampat OR somemore";
$twitter_number_of_tweets = 2;
$twitter_hashtags = "ashwinsampat+OR+franq2+OR+franq2.net";

// Instantiate a Twitter object which will scan Twitter depending on the parameters
$twitter = new Twitter($twitter_username_string, $twitter_number_of_tweets, $twitter_hashtags);
$tweets = $twitter->getTweets();

foreach ( $tweets as $tweet )
{
    $tweetoutput_secondline = "<p>".$tweet->title." <em>Tweeted by <a href=".$tweet->permalink." target=_blank title=@".$tweet->user.">".$tweet->author."</em></a></p>";
}

$myFile = "export_file_twitter_output";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $tweetoutput;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

$filename = 'export_file_twitter_output';
$somecontent = "$tweetoutput_secondline";

// Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.
if (is_writable($filename)) {

    // In our example we're opening $filename in append mode.
    // The file pointer is at the bottom of the file hence
    // that's where $somecontent will go when we fwrite() it.
    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
         echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
         exit;
    }

    // Write $somecontent to our opened file.
    if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }

    fclose($handle);

} else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of duplication here. The code

1. downloads one tweet, then stores it in the `$tweetoutput` variable,
2. downloads two tweets, then stores the second in the `$tweetoutput_secondline` variable,
3. opens a file called `export_file_twitter_output`, then writes the first tweet into it (and closes the file),
4. opens the same `export_file_twitter_output` file and writes the second tweet into it (and closes the file).

I'd download simultaneously the two tweets (`$twitter_number_of_tweets = 2`), then store both in the same variable:

```
$tweetoutput = "";
foreach ( $tweets as $tweet )
{
    $tweetoutput .= "<p>" . $tweet->title . " <em>Tweeted by <a href=" .
        $tweet->permalink .
        " target=_blank title=@" . $tweet->user . ">" .
        $tweet->author . "</em></a></p>\n";
}
```

(Note the `.=`.)

After that I'd write the contents of `$tweetoutput` to the file in one step. This would remove a lot of code duplication and it would work with only one network connection instead of two.

I prefer the second file-writing code, it has error handling on `fwrite` and it checks that the file is writable before opening.

I'd also change the string concatenation to [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) inside the `foreach` loop. It would result more readable code.